# I’m worried about being near pets due to past issues

Tags: cats, psychology

I live with a cat, she’s the cutest thing in the world, she’s also a runt, and still is the size of a kitten, yet she’s about 3. I’ve not physically hurt her, but sometimes I’ve forced her to sit with me when she doesn’t want to.

Today she nearly broke my headphones because she was walking over them and made them fall and I got annoyed and put her in air prison, I held her in the air for a few seconds, but then I shook her a little bit. I feel so terrible for shaking her, I just got really upset, as my headphones are my special item and I can’t do anything without them and if she broke them I’d have been so upset. I was just so scared because for me, I experience emotions strongly and it felt like my world had fallen apart for a few seconds when she nearly broke them, and then I was so upset with her for making me feel so sad.

Now I’m extremely worried as I don’t want to hurt her, but I know I can’t control my emotions when it comes to my special things, but I still love her so much and can’t just stop going near her.

I have autism and PDA and I have never hurt her before as I keep my emotions in line, but I feel so terrible. I haven’t stopped crying for hours thinking about how scared and hurt I have made her. I’m 15 and I love animals so much but I’m worried if I own one I’d just force them to sit with me and play with me when they don’t want to and then they will have trauma because of me. If this means that I can’t have animals I will be devastated, but I’d rather have the animals safe instead of me being selfish and keeping them, when I may harm them. I think I should tell my family about what has happened, they will be understanding, it’s not like I’ll get told off, and they will make sure the cat is safe. Please if anyone could help me with some advice I’d appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to Pets.SE, asking a question such as this shows courage and that your heart is in the right place. I feel it would probably best to discuss the event with your family and share your concerns. I think for the moment you should not interact with the cat without supervision, but the fact that you are thinking about giving it up to protect it shows you have a very important trait for having pets, putting the pets needs first and your own second.

Comment: You are asking this question because you want to do the best for your pet, which is what matters. As a temporary solution, try to keep anything special in safe locations. Make sure anything of value is further away from edges and that your cat wouldn't be able to accidentally knock it over.

Comment: I'd actually say that its a good idea to have that as a permanent thing.  Small animals tend to be a little klutzy and I had to rescue my very well behaved dog from behind my desk too many times as he got older.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! I agree with the comments before. But to make a good shaped question here, you should add a certain question or an aim, you want to reach. This gives you more focused answers, which will be more helpful. If you have more than one aim, or question, then it is welcome you make mire than one post. You can link them, to not need to write all again.

Comment: I recommend seeking out an autism community for help. The people here have knowledge about pets, but not necessarily autism, and so the advice you receive here may or may not be helpful to you. Meanwhile I imagine there are many successful pet owners in the autism community who probably could give more useful advice.